# Reset password link resets password but new password is not recognized by login.php

Tags: php, php-password-hash

I created a forgot password link and everything works(password resets, token is set back to " ", password is properly hashed) but when I try to login with my new password, my script login.inc.php is not able to recognize the new password. I also get no errors whatsoever. If anyone can teach me what I have done wrong, I would really appreciate it.

reset-password.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include 'database/login-dbh.php';

    if (isset($_GET["email"]) && isset($_GET["token"])) {

        $email = $_GET['email'];
        $token = $_GET['token'];

        $sql = "SELECT id FROM user WHERE email='$email' AND token='$token'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($num_rows > 0) {
            $str = "0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
            $str = str_shuffle($str);
            $str = substr($str, 0, 35);

            $password = password_hash($str, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            $sql = "UPDATE user SET password='$password', token='' WHERE email='$email'";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            echo "Your new password is: $str";
        }     
    }else{
        header("Location: forgot-password.php?error=token+not+found");
        exit();
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Yahbang</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet/forgotpassword-style.css">
</head>
<header>

</header>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

login.inc.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include '../database/login-dbh.php';

$email = $_POST['email'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];


$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email= ? ";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $email);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if(password_verify($pwd, $row['password'])) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];   
    $userID = $row['id'];

    header("Location: ../index.php?id=$userID");
    exit();
} else {
   header("Location: ../index.php?error=login");
   exit();
} 

?>
```

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: I didn't ask about security. if you can't answer then don't.

Comment: @user9098801 he didn't answer - he provided a very helpful comment.

Comment: But this whole process is about security, thats why you make people login

Comment: Its just a thought, but did you check that your `password` column is large enough to hold the hash? How is your `password` column defined in your schema?

Comment: @user9098801 What is the output you get when you add `var_dump($str, $password)` to your reset-password.php file before you send the SQL query. And what is the output you get when you add `var_dump($pwd, $row['password']);` before your `password_verify()` check? Please edit your question to include the output you get from these `var_dump()` calls.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your reset-password.php file is insecure because you are subject to SQL injection. You should NEVER use a `GET / POST` variable directly in a SQL statement. Always protect the variable first (there are many posts on this).

This said, I'd need to see your `password_verify()` function. To debug, here are a few tricks I use:

- Print your `$_POST` variables you're receiving: `print_r($_POST);`
- Print your SQL statement
- Print the result of your $row variable: `print_r($row);`

Somewhere in there, you're missing something, but with these simple tricks, you'll find them out.